# Visual focus on the comment flag icon seems to have vanished when tabbing

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility, keyboard, focus

When I'm using <kbd>tab</kbd> to move the focus around on the page, most things have a visual indication of where the focus is (which is a relatively recent change; thank you). I often use this to flag comments - if I click on a link to a comment, I can press <kbd>tab</kbd> once and it will focus on the upvote button; another press and it focuses on the flag icon. I use this fairly often.

So I was surprised this morning when I noticed that the focus on the flag icon seems to have vanished. While the focus still moves to the flag, and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> presses it, it no longer has a visual indicator. As I pointed out [almost exactly a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320404/294691), it's important that things have a visual indicator when the keyboard focus is on it.

Here are some screenshots that show what I mean. (Comment chosen at random.)

This is a focus on the upvote button:

[image: screenshot showing blue square around the upvote button a comment]

Then I press <kbd>tab</kbd> once and I see this:

[image: screenshot showing comment with no visual focus indicator anywhere]

...no focus indicator. If I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, though, it will open the flag dialogue.

And if I press <kbd>tab</kbd> again, the focus moves to the user link, which still has a focus indicator:

[image: screenshot showing visual focus indicator on link to user]

It seems like just the focus indicator on the flag icon has disappeared, very recently. (I'm 99.99% sure it was there.) Could we please put it back?

I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can't confirm this. Using current firefox I see the visual focus for the flag.

Comment: Can confirm this on Chrome. The CSS rule `.s-btn:focus` is removing the outline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. Focus on comment flags should be more noticeable now.

[image: flag focus screenshot]